# Отображение шрифтов Google на canvas

Tags: javascript, html, canvas, шрифты, google-fonts

Имеется приложение, на главной странице канвас с текстом. В приложении есть функционал смены языка (русский, английский). На канвасе текст имеет шрифт [Roboto Mono](https://fonts.google.com/specimen/Roboto+Mono?selection.family=Roboto%20Mono).
У меня была проблема с тем, что шрифт Roboto Mono отображался на канвасе не сразу, а только после какого либо взаимодействия с канвасом. Эта проблема не проявляется, если добавить в html как либо фиктивный элемент со шрифтом Roboto Mono. То есть, как я понял, браузер начинает подгружать шрифты, только когда они появляются на странице.
Если подгружать шрифт таким образом

```
  <link rel='prefetch' href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Roboto+Mono:500" as="style"
onload="this.rel='stylesheet'">
```

[Example jsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/alexaaaant/0qp3rwmg/1/)
То мы можем видеть, что шрифт не применился (он применится, при перерисовке канваса), но в консоле разработчика во вкладке network мы видим, что шрифты загрузились.[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

После этого я подумал, что было бы логично подгружать шрифты заранее, перед отрисовкой текста на канвасе. 
С помощью этого [вопроса](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29315787/draw-to-canvas-only-after-google-web-font-is-loaded) я реализовал нечто подобное [Example jsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/alexaaaant/x3qsjyov/)

Теперь мы видим, что шрифт подгрузился и отобразился корректно. Так же теперь в network мы видим, что появился запрос непосредственно к файлу шрифта [image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Но обратите внимание на пример, мы начинаем загружать шрифты в методе onload объекта window, то есть, когда загрузилась вся страница, включая стили, картинки и другие ресурсы и только после этого мы начали рисовать на канвасе текст. 
Если мы вынесем загрузку шрифтов из onload, а отрисовку текста оставим там, то шрифт загрузится, но не отобразится на канвасе.
[Example jsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/alexaaaant/qp0mx2wo/3/) К сожалению это почему то не воспроизводится в jsFiddle, даже если очистить кэш. Но можете создать html файл и проверить на нем, проблема воспроизведется.
В network мы увидим, что шрифт загрузился! Но опять же, отобразится он только при переотрисовке канваса
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
То есть все корректно работает, если начать загрузку шрифтов в onload, а потом, после того, как все шрифты загружены начинать отрисовку на канвасе. Может кто нибудь объяснить, почему так происходит? Почему если начать предварительно грузить шрифты, не в onload, то они на канвасе не отображаются.

Напомню, что в приложении имеется два языка, русский и английский. Вернемся к рабочему примеру с загрузкой шрифта в onload. Загрузим два шрифта на латинице и кириллице, напишем на канвасе текст на английском и на русском языке.
[ExampleJsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/alexaaaant/d32eLofa/) Что мы видим? Что подрузился только английский шрифт!
Обратите внимание на эту строчку, первым мы указали latin:

```
      google: { families: ['Roboto Mono:500:latin,cyrillic'] },
```

Если поставить на первое место cyrillic, то на успешно подгрузится только русский шрифт! В network мы видим, что загрузку одного шрифта начал объект webfont, а другого сам canvas! 
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Кто нибудь может объяснить как и почему это так работает? Как можно исправить этот баг?

Answer (score 0):

Я вот так подгружал на canvas в своих проектах:

````
const font  = new FontFace('Alternity', 'url(Alternity.otf)');
font.load().then(function() {
  document.fonts.add(font);
  context.font = "48px Alternity";
  context.fillText("merrymaker14", width / 2 - 75, height - 25);
})```
````

Comment: Пробовал этот метод. Но мне необходимо подгрузить два языка

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/FontFaceSet

Comment: Это решает проблему с корректным отображением двух языков на канвасе? По-моему нет